# 'It wasn't what I expected' vs 'It wasn't what I expected it to be'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Can you please tell me the difference between these examples?

1. it wasn't what I thought
2. it wasn't what I thought it was
3. it wasn't what I expected
4. it wasn't what I expected it to be

I feel like 1 and 3, and 2 and 4 are pretty much the same.

here is my understanding

ex) I go to a restaurant which I found online and got a great review, and it turns out to be a bad restaurant. Then I can say, "it wasn't what I expected or it wasn't what I thought."

And one day I went to a restaurant and it was great. A few months later, I revisited the restaurant and found it really bad. Then I can also say, "it wasn't what I expected it to be or it wasn't what I thought it was."

am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your understanding of these phrases.

However, here are some other phrases that you could use that would be more casual/relaxed:

Scenario #1: "You could say "That restaurant didn't live up the the hype." or "I don't know what everyone was talking about, that restaurant was awful."

Scenario #2: you could say "I'm not sure what happened, but that restaurant isn't as good as it used to be."